# Rails 3.1 & Jasmine: Including JavaScripts from gems

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, rails-3.1

I have a rails 3.1 project that I'd like to run some jasmine specs on. Problem is, my rails project requires some javascript files that are sourced from gems (most particularly backbone-rails), not my /assets directory.

Looking at the generated jasmine file's HTML, it's successfully including all assets from the JavaScripts /assets directory (compiled from coffeescript), but no javascript files generated by gems. Consequently I'm getting a bunch of 'class not found' errors.

So, any ideas on getting jasmine to require Rails 3.1 JavaScript files from gems, not just /assets? Current jasmine.yml included below. Any ideas appreciated

```
src_files:
  - public/javascripts/prototype.js
  - public/javascripts/effects.js
  - public/javascripts/controls.js
  - public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
  - public/javascripts/application.js
  - public/javascripts/**/*.js
  - spec/**/*_spec.js
  - "vendor/**/*.{js, coffee}"
  - "lib/**/*.{js, coffee}"
  - "app/**/*.{js, coffee}"

stylesheets:
  - stylesheets/**/*.css

helpers:
  - helpers/**/*.js

spec_files:
  - '**/*[sS]pec.{js, coffee}'

src_dir: assets

spec_dir: spec/javascripts
```

Comment: What is your method to run tests: ad hoc or through a CI/deploy strategy?

Comment: rxgx: At the moment, ad hoc. Rake jasmine; localhost:8888

Comment: Do any of the gems require you to run a rake task to generate the javascript or stylesheets?

Comment: rxgx: No, the backbone.js javascript is sourced from the /lib folder of the gem, not generated into the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend using [`jasmine-headless-webkit`](http://johnbintz.github.com/jasmine-headless-webkit/) to do jasmine testing in rails 3.1 apps.  Here's my `jasmine.yml` file:

```
src_dir: app/assets/javascripts
asset_paths:
- app/assets/templates
- lib/assets/javascripts
- vendor/assets/javascripts

src_files:
- [ 'application.js' ]

spec_dir: spec/javascripts

spec_files:
- "**/*[Ss]pec.*"

helpers:
- "helpers/**/*"
```

I'm using that with `jasmine-headless-webkit` to run my tests on the command-line (using [`watchr`](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr/) to run them automatically when a file is changed)

It's a wonderful way to test.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly recent commits to jasmine master enable it to source javascripts from the asset pipeline. It works great.

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/commits/master

Comment: It sounds like his problem is for javascripts that aren't in the asset pipeline.